# Designing circuit with Arduino and optocoupler: beginners problem

Tags: arduino, voltage, resistors, optoelectronics

Firstly, I am a beginning hobbyist starting doing some electronics and this is my absolutely first attempt in trying to automate something. Here is my circuit (or what I intend):

[image: Schematic]

I don't know if my circuit-design is correct or not. If not, feel free to comment on it with suggestion to make it better next time.

**What I intend to do:**

Let me explain my intention in my circuit. As soon as the power is switched on (the power to DC motor is already on but needs to be activated with the optocoupler-U1 in the figure), the led L2, L3, L4 in the figure (actually lasers, but should mean the same thing in this case) comes on and strikes the photo-resistors R7, R8 and R9 in the figure. Thus their resistance becomes low and the voltage across R1, R2 and R3 which goes to their respective input pins to Arduino become high. Also the motor and L1-inductor (actually solenoid valve) gets their power from 12 V supply. I have isolated two circuits because motor draws 1A current and I think this might be the best way to separate two circuits.

The motor is actually the pump which draws liquid from the tube. As soon as liquid reaches certain level, L2 light emission is blocked by liquid and R1 goes low. When that happens, the output from Arduino (denoted by line crossed with slanting orange line) is set high which equalizes the voltage across R4 to be zero and the motor is then stopped for remainder of time. Now the liquid starts moving downwards again since the pump is off. As soon as it gets below L3, timer kicks in Arduino and starts recording time which eventually stops when the liquid level gets below L4.

The pump firstly draws the liquid up crossing all L2, L3 and L4.

**My problem:**

Actually, nothing serious. However since I am just starting doing stuff like this, I would like to be sure before attaching the circuit and make sure that my Arduino does not get fried. I am thinking about common ground between Arduino, the LED and photo-resistor circuit plus the circuit of motor with 1A current. Does common ground pose some problem in my case? Is something wrong in my circuit that needs to be rectified.

I have not given the values for the resistance because I can do the math but I want to check the accuracy of my circuit.

Comment: You need to provide part numbers and values. It is highly unlikely that U1 will drive 1A. You should not use the same letter (L) to designate both LEDs and inductors. You will need a flyback diode in parallel with your motor/solenoid.

Comment: Thanks, I completely failed to check that 4N35 will drive 1A current. Your are right. I checked the specs and it looks like 4N35 is capable of delivering about 100 mA tops with max power rating of about 0.15 watts. Can you suggest me any options to 4N35/U1? Also what is flyback diode? Is it just normal diode you mean set to avoid back-emf?

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit rushed. I would suggest an N-channel MOSFET as a low-side driver for the motor/solenoid. Yes a flyback diode is basically a normal diode to provide a current path back to the power supply to avoid back emf (sometimes a schottky diode for speed). There are other alternatives. You will need to make sure both your diode and MOSFET can handle the current and that the MOSFET has a low enough gate threshold voltage for your Arduino which I assume outputs at 3.3V.